# Is it against code to splice wires inside of the load center?

Tags: electrical

So I was working on breaking a tandem 15A single-pole breaker into two 15A single pole breakers, one being a Combination AFCI.  After getting the panel open and moving one circuit to a new, 15A single pole (non-CAFCI), I discovered that my second circuit, the one I want on the CAFCI, has too short of a neutral wire to reach the CAFCI breaker's neutral screw.  It looks to have been shortened to be just long enough to reach the neutral bus bar.

Is it against code to splice/pigtail a new, short piece of romex onto the existing neutral (w/ a wire cap) so I can connect it to the CAFCI's neutral screw?

This relates to [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/28646).  I was replacing the AFCI receptacle with a CAFCI breaker, on the advice of an electrician, when I encountered this short neutral wire inside the panel.  The electronics and sensing apparatus inside of an actual CAFCI breaker have been around long enough that most of the kinks have been worked out.  The Leviton AFCI Receptacle, OTOH, is still fairly new and might not be usable in all wiring configurations yet.

Comment: It's fine and common practice.

Comment: Others have said it is fine, I will just add that just because you can, does not mean you should: try to avoid it unless it is necessary, otherwise you risk having a bunch of extra crap in the box making things more difficult to understand. For example, I had to rework some of the garage circuit, so I move those splices to a separate junction box a foot away and ran fresh Romex between the two. Throw up a sticker with the circuit number on the box and wammo, all three garage splices are in the same box, and the load center is still nice and neat and organized.

Comment: @John: As mentioned in my question, the neutral wire coming out of the romex for the circuit in question is literally too short.  There really is no other way, short of opening the wall up and replacing that romex run, to avoid this.  And to add, the breaker panel is recessed on a wall in my living room, not down in a basement (because I don't have a basement).  Small house :)

Comment: @Kumba I know, that is why I said "try to avoid it unless it is necessary" and it is necessary in this situation. Please keep in mind that people find these SE questions years later via Google looking for similar issues.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> ## National Electrical Code 2011
>
> ### Chapter 3 Wiring Methods and Materials
>
> ### Article 312 Cabinets, Cutout Boxes, and Meter Socket Enclosures
>
> #### I. Installation
>
> **312.8 Switch and Overcurrent Device Enclosures with Splices, Taps, and Feed- Through Conductors.** The wiring space of enclosures for switches or overcurrent devices
> shall be permitted for conductors feeding through, spliced, or tapping
> off to other enclosures, switches, or overcurrent devices where all of
> the following conditions are met:
>
> (1)   The total of all conductors installed at any cross section of the
> wiring space does not exceed 40 percent of the cross-sectional area of
> that space.
>
> (2)   The total area of all conductors, splices, and taps installed at
> any cross section of the wiring space does not exceed 75 percent of
> the cross-sectional area of that space.
>
> (3)   A warning label is applied to the enclosure that identifies the closest            disconnecting means for any feed-through conductors.

This is the applicable code section. It used to say no splices were allowed unless there is enough room. This led many, many folks to simply state "NO splices allowed". They were wrong.
You'd be amazed at what it would physically take to reach that 75% number of fill.

So basically yes, splices are FINE in a breaker panel.

Comment: And, in fact, they aren't uncommon during box replacement, when getting a clean layout may require a few splices.

Comment: Splices in the panel are also common when installing transfer switches for generators.

Comment: @speedyPetey When quoting NEC (or any code) please include the code version (year), since code numbers and verbiage change from time to time.

Comment: OK, makes sense. At the same time Tester, it is not necessary for you to edit my posts so that they look exactly like all of yours. The intent is known as is the code section. Is there a requirement on this site that posts such as this all look the same?

Comment: @SpeedyPetey I'll mention something about this in the meta section of this site.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey see http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/941/copyright-on-images-fair-use-of-text-full-text-excerpts-of-code-books

Comment: OK, I'm not sure what you are stating here. It seems as if you are saying that by quoting the whole section, as Tester did in editing my post, it is over the line, but just quoting the section relating to the question is OK? 
Personally I don't even remotely see quoting one small section as "replacing the need for the original". It should be quite obvious that a DIYer looking for the proper way to do one small job is NOT going to drop $150 on a code book to find out what's right. He'll ask around until he gets his answers.

Comment: There is no problem [quoting sections of NEC](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/q/532/33). @SpeedyPetey I edit to include relevant section titles, to make it easier for folks to find this information in the original texts. Code sections do move around from time to time, and it makes it easier to locate the information in the future if you have a bit of extra information.

Comment: @Speedy Petey: Funny thing is, I actually have a copy of the 2011 NEC code book.  I just wouldn't have known where, in its ~850 pages, to start looking.  Likely because I don't call my panel a "cabinet" or "enclosure for overcurrent devices" or other such term, but either an "electrical panel" or "breaker box".

Comment: It's a BIG book, but you get used to it and how to use it. I tell people that all the time. If you know how to use the book you could know nothing and still pass a test. If you are not sure where to go searching the right terms is key.

I've been using electronic copies for years now and like it SO much better.

Comment: @Tester101 - I thought that splices had to have a connection to box right?  I had an inspector tell me that I can't use it to pass through wires.

Comment: See http://www.nfpa.org/codes-and-standards/free-access

Answer (score 6):

It's fine.  Someone else may be able to provide a code reference, but in general your breaker box is a junction box, it's sealed, and splices are normal.

Comment: Bryce: I wish I could assign points for "assisted answer" or such, but I gave it to Speedy for citing the relevant code bits.  Thanks!