# Neutral wire too short to new CAFCI breaker

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

Initially builder installed a normal 15 amp non AFCI breaker in the service panel box for a unfinished basement. Now I am finishing basement, and I have done electricity in my basement. now fun part is started.

As per electric code, I have to replace the existing breaker with a 15 amp combination AFCI breaker.  initially neutral wire was attached to neutral bar. But now since I have combination AFCI breaker I have to attach the neutral wire to circuit breaker first. but the neutral wire is too short. damn!

its not easy to pull out existing 15 amp wire from the box.

[image]
[image]
Please assist. thanks!

Thanks !

Comment: can you not add a connection and extent the wire? Otherwise what else can you do if the cable does not reach?

Comment: Think you can add a simple junction box near the panel and splice extra cable/wire from there to inside the panel.  Do not think you can use simple wire nut connection inside panel itself.

Comment: @crip659: _"Do not think you can use simple wire nut connection inside panel itself"_ -- can you elaborate on that? Because, the electrician that did the work for our home definitely did exactly that, in the couple of places breakers needed to be moved and they hadn't left enough wire. They just spliced in some extra length with a wire nut. And according to posts on this site, it seems to be legal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it against code to splice wires inside of the load center?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/39798/is-it-against-code-to-splice-wires-inside-of-the-load-center)

Comment: To the OP: You should be able to just extend the wire with a splice. See proposed duplicate.

Comment: @PeterDuniho  Mine used a junction box on the side.  Seems like code allows splices in panel, from your link.  Maybe make an answer for the OP.

Comment: Depends where you live.