# 14/3 feeding two lighting circuits

Tags: electrical

Can you run a 14/3 to feed two separate zones of lights? Two breakers Two hot legs feeding 2 lighting circuits each with their own switch, and share the neutral?

Comment: See [What is a multiwire branch circuit?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/71652/what-is-a-multiwire-branch-circuit).

Comment: Two breakers *but you have to handle-tie them*.  But yes, I do exactly that in my shop.  Also in many locations they will need GFCI or AFCI, doing that on tied breakers will be complicated, hard and expensive.

Comment: If I can would I be better of to run 2 14/2’s?