# How can I add a GFCI receptacle on a circuit with split receptacles?

Tags: electrical, wiring, gfci

I have a typically wired living room with all receptacles switchable on the top outlet. We are installing a large fish tank and decided to add GFCI protection. I'm trying to change a single duplex to a GFCI + single duplex. I would like this box for the fish tank to be hot at all times. I tied together the switchable lead in this box so everything downstream is still the same. I fed the hot circuit through the GFCI and jumped to the neighboring duplex. You see where this is going? I didn't until I flipped the light switch. Shared neutral returning current not seen leaving the GFCI. Is there a way around this without pulling wire? Or do I have to live with switchable top outlets in this box?

Comment: Note that if the switches are the only means of switched lighting in the room at least one will have to stay that way to stay within the NEC.

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/9332/33) which has a diagram showing how to wire a GFCI in a shared "neutral" situation. Unfortunately, in your situation you won't be able to provide GFCI protection to the other receptacles. Unless of course, you pull an additional wire throughout the rest of the circuit.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, pigtail the GFCI on both hot and neutral side.  Do not attempt to daisychain any other outlets off the "load" side of the GFCI.