# Clarification on sharing a neutral for 2 circuits

Tags: electrical

This is a followup question to [this answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/9332)

I plan to do something quite similar to the diagram Tester101 posted. I will pull 3-wire (10/3+g) into a junction box and then pull 2 separate 2 wires (12/2+g) from the J box to GFCI outlets. Here are the things I am looking for clarification on...

--Can I run two 20amp circuits with the above configuration?

--If so, will the dual pole breaker be labeled "40 amp" back at the panel? (like a large appliance 240v breaker, or is there some other kind of dual pole breaker that I should look for?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll use a double pole 20 ampere breaker. It will have two handles that are tied together, and will say "20" on the handles.

It should look similar to this...

[image]
<sub>(source: [homedepot.com](http://www.homedepot.com/catalog/productImages/400/d5/d5896b94-73d2-4c35-b7d5-88346e4795f7_400.jpg))</sub>

I'm not sure why you're planning to run 10 AWG conductors, but typically 20 ampere circuits only require 12 AWG conductors.

Comment: That's helpful, thanks. One addendum to this question: Does it matter if the two circuits that share a neutral do not both go to GFI outlets? I am thinking of using one circuit for an electric stove top and the other for a GFI outlet. Any problem with that configuration (in terms of GFI tripping or otherwise)?

Comment: No, both legs do not have to feed GFCI receptacles.  Not sure about the legitimacy of using one leg for a cooktop though.

Comment: Why might the cooktop be a problem? This is a 110v 2-burner cooktop rated to be used on a single 20amp circuit. Is it a code issue perhaps, that the cooktop is supposed to have its own "dedicated circuit"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a perfectly valid configuration.

The breaker will be labeled as a "20 Amp" breaker. The breaker ratings are per-conductor and not total current.

They generally look just like the "large appliance 240v breaker", though there do exist some which put four breakers in one module called a "quad". One uses the quad breakers when there are no empty slots in the breaker box (though one must double-check that the box is certified to be able to be used with the "quad" breakers").

Comment: How would a quad breaker help if there were no empty slots?