# Adding GFCI to box with 2 hot (black and red) and 1 neutral with one wire

Tags: electrical

I moved into an older home and i am trying to add a GFCI in a kitchen outlet by the sink.  Its a two gang box with a switch and one outlet, it has 3 lines coming into the box, two go to the light switch and only one 14/3 wire connecting to the outlet.

On the 14/3 wire going to the outlet both the red and black wires are live.  the way it is connected currently the neutral is shared and jumped at the outlet (picture attached).

How can i install a GFCI if there are two hot lines?
[image]

[image]

Comment: [This answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/9332/33) might be helpful.

Comment: ok so it is acceptable if i connect two wires from the neutral points on the GFCI outlet and connect (pigtail) them to the existing neutral from the line with a wire nut / marrette?   if i read the linked post correctly as i only want the one GFCI recepticle

Comment: nm i re-read the linked post......so basically the way my setup is the outlet (where i want to put the GFCI) is currently not the first receptacle on the circuit so my only option is to feed new wire?

Comment: I don't know where on the circuit that receptacle is. All I know is that it's a split receptacle, and likely fed by a multiwire branch circuit.