# convert 220v range outlet to 110v standard

Tags: electrical

converting old electric range to gas range, and need a standard 110V outlet - can I re-configure the existing 220V outlet and existing wiring, replacing only outlet and breaker in a legal (code compliant) manner?

Comment: Typically yes, it's best to shut off the breaker and pull the outlet out of the box exposing the wires then post a picture showing the number and type of wire in the box to avoid getting vague answers.

Comment: Does [this existing question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/81628/can-i-take-a-220-line-and-convert-it-to-a-regular-house-outlet-what-would-be-the) help?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes in question please? Also, what make and model is your breaker panel?

Comment: thanks - it'll be a while before I can post pics - will try to do that in a few weeks

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Due to the wire size you will likely need to pig tail (with appropriately sized wire nuts in both locations) to fit into the new breaker (20 amp) and outlet. Since you'll be removing a 2 pole breaker and replacing it with a single pole breaker, you'll have an exposed slot in your cover plate on the panel. Some ppl around here suggest putting in a "spare" breaker to fill the hole, but you can also buy an insert to "plug the slot".

EDIT:  Just saw "NoSparksPlease" comment and agree.  Let's get a peek at the boxes before we go too hog wild here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe.  It depends on what the existing wires look like.  You can’t take it for granted.