# How should I connect a GFCI outlet and light switch?

Tags: switch, gfci, light

I am connecting a GFCI outlet and a light circuit to a 4 wire (Black, Red, Neutral, Ground) two gang box. The switch is on the right and the duplex GFCI is on the left (near kitchen sink).  How do I connect these properly?  I saw an example that connected the GFCI to an additional outlet with a 4 wire connection.

See: [How do I install a GFCI receptacle with two hot wires and common neutral?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/9293/how-do-i-install-a-gfci-receptacle-with-two-hot-wires-and-common-neutral)?

Would this wiring work for this situation?

Comment: Do you have an outlet controlled by the switch?  or maybe the switch controls a garbage disposal?   This could be a multi wire branch circuit (MWBC), not uncommon in kitchens.  Is this a new install or are you replacing the outlet and/or switch?  If replacing, hopefully you took pics BEFORE you took it apart, if so, please post them.

Comment: Is there another cable that goes to the light? Is this a new circuit or an old circuit? If these are the *only* wires in the box and it used to work, then you *probably* have black = incoming hot, red = outgoing switched hot, white = neutral. But if this is new, anything is possible. Does the light need to GFCI protected? Where is the light getting its neutral from? Pictures of your actual switch/receptacle box showing any existing wiring *and* a picture showing wiring at the light fixture would help.

Comment: The GFCI has warning tape covering a second set of terminals. Do not peel off the tape! Leave it alone and then read the instructions for how you attach 2 wires to the "Line" terminals.   That will steer you clear of *most* mistakes in this area.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.  I have 4 wires.  Black, Red, White, Ground coming into the box from the panel.  For the light, I have 2 wire ( Balck, White, Ground) from the light switch to the light.